Where is the water pressure valve?

My pressure is well below 1 and close to zero. Trying figure out which lever to pull to increase pressure.




Where did you measure the pressure? Are you on city water? Well? If city look at where the main comes in off the street. It should be very close to your main shutoff for the house.

I have three pressure gauges. Two are visible in the images and I have another one on my air to water ecodan system. They all show close to zero pressure. I'm not in city. Rural

Start at the source. If you're on well your pump may be malfunctioning. Can you measure pressure right after the pump as it enters the house? A $10 screw on pressure gauge will work if you have a hose bib on the line near the pump.

Does rural=well?

Not every system has a pressure regulator. A PRV is used to reduce pressure if it's too high coming in off the street. If you're on a well you probably wouldn't have one.

I don't think it's a well. Water comes in from mains.i don't think I have a pump either. I think I just need to turn a lever or screw but not sure where

If your water pressure was fine and now it's not, something malfunctioned and I doubt it will be solved with an adjustment screw. You need to talk with whoever told you that and you also need to find out where your water is sourced.

What was the BAR reading before?

I cannot recall. I've only started learning last few days. Wouldn't have paid attention to it before
